# iterating through objects of response JSON

Tags: c#, json, hashtable

I'm doing a query and get as result something like this, which i put into a Hashtable

```
{"success":"true", "result":[{"type":"email", "address":"aaasd@asd.com"},{"type":"email", "address":"aaasddee@dse.com"}]}
```

then i do

```
return hashtable["result"];
```

so I only have this left

```
[{"type":"email", "address":"aaasd@asd.com"},{"type":"email", "address":"aaasddee@dse.com"}]
```

but my problem is that I don't know how to iterate through every object from "result" to fill my own objects. I was searching for a solution but the only answer I found was to use

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in searchResult) {
//do something<br>
}
```

When I iterate through the Hashtable like this I can only use the properties `entry.Key` and `entry.Value` but I can't say which value for a specific key I need. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You should look into a library like JSON.NET to do this kind of deserialization for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using deserialising using JSON.NET as shown below :-

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(searchResult);
```

You can create your class like below :-

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

For more information :-

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that matches the signature of the result collection like:

```
public class Result
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then use Json.NET to parse the result node into a `List<Result>`. There is plenty of documentation online on how to use the Json.NET library.

Hope that helps,
Rob